# How to route to a hidden pin in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, layout, altium, routing

I'm using *Altium Designer 14.2.3* and I have a connector on which are always two pins connected to each other. In my schematic library I have configured the Pins to be hidden and connected to the other. (e.g Pin 7: hide [x] Connect To 6)

In the PCB I want to route to both pins for having a better connection, but altium doesn't let me do this.

[image: R4 should be connected to both pins]

As shown in the image I want to connect R4 to pin 1 AND 12. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "connect to" you should write the net name, not the pin number.

Comment: This would make sense. But I don't get how I could use a component from a library in different schematics when I have the pin connected to a defined net name. Do I have to use always the same net names when using this component? Should I use this method only for VCC and GND Pins?

Comment: I found the solution. I leave the Pins connected to the Pin number in the library and in the schematic I edit the component in `Properties > Edit Pins... > Edit` to set the net label for each pin. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: that's the reason i've given up to use this function in AD )))

Comment: This issue is also explained [here](http://www.mbedded.ninja/electronics/general/altium/altium-bugs-and-things-to-watch-out-for#hidden-pins-on-schematics-can8217t-be-attached-to-visible-pins).